# Accident with a lot of indexed pages - Google is not happy

Tags: seo, sitemap, search-engine-indexing, negative-seo

We had more than 500 pages indexed, we are a relatively new site but I think we have good content so Google was ok with our pages.

Most of this pages were profiles and had a url structure like /place/place/work
One of our engineers changed the url structure and with that, updated the sitemap.

The old url's starting throwing 404 because he didn't put any 301 redirection to the new ones and Google was not happy at all about this.

Google de inxeded most of the pages and now we have only 75 indexed and 10 of them are profiles.

This engineer was obviously at fault, but 2 weeks have passed and our indexed pages are still 75.

Any tip on this? We have put a lot of effort for this pages to be seo friendly but it seems google dont trust us anymore :(

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

It's not that Google is unhappy with you but rather that you are seeing a typical "new site" spidering/update schedule.

Very few sites get indexed/updated by Google daily and almost none of those sites are new.  What most likely happened is your site was indexed based on the first iteration, then those pages dropped after the mistake and now you have to wait a little while for the indexer to catch up and republish.

tl;dr you may be panicking too soon.  Just be patient and things will get re-indexed so long as you remain stable.

PS - You can still add the 301 redirection...

Comment: As a side note for the OP, it is not always necessary to add 301 redirects when the new pages can be found easily and the old pages are gone. Google does prefer a 404 or 410 when a page is gone. You only add a 301 when it is important for users or to preserve any link value which is unlikely for profile pages.